# Open source .NET library for automatic Russian text summarization

Tags: c#, .net, data-analysis, nlp, language

I need a library to automatically summarize a text written in Russian.

Requirements:

- Summarize a text (for instance from 5000 characters to 500 characters)
- Works with Russian
- Open source
- Usable from my C# code